# Substituting within a function definition that includes Simplify

Tags: functions, programming, syntax

I would like to define a function like

```
myfunc[f_] := Simplify[(f/g)]
```

where g will be substituted/replaced with the current value of g at the time of definition. In practise, g will be complicated and myfunc will be defined over and over again. However, between these redefinitions I want it to be statically set. If

```
g=1+x^2
```

then I want the equivalent of typing

```
myfunc[f_] := Simplify[(f/(1+x^2))]
```

The following works but seems pretty arcane:

```
myfuncA[f_] := Evaluate[With[{yy = g}, Hold[Simplify[f/yy]]]]

myfunc[f_] := ReleaseHold[myfuncA[f]]
```

How to accomplish this simple task?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: `myfunc[f_] := Simplify[(f/g)] /. (g -> 1 + x^2)`

Comment: If the substitution for g were to be made for one particular instance and the value substituted was simple then this construction would work. In my example, the 1+x^2 is a placeholder for a complicated expression calculated elsewhere over and over again. So this particular method doesn't provide the flexibility I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that **value injection using** `With` will work for you.

Let's first define the sample `g` value you want:

```
g = 1 + x^2
```

Now we define `myfunc` injecting the current definition of g inside its definition:

```
Clear[myfunc]
With[{g = g}, myfunc[f_] := Simplify[f/g]]
```

Now let's change the value of `g` and check whether the definition of `myfunc` is affected:

```
g = 3;

myfunc[expr]
(* Out: expr/(1+x^2) *)

myfunc[1 + x^2 - x^3 - x^5]
(* Out: 1 - x^3 *)
```

Comment: This works and is the prototypical construction needed!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
g = 1 + x^2
Unprotect[saveg]
saveg = g;
myfunc[f_] := Simplify[(f/saveg)]
Protect[saveg]
```